# markov chain: how to find the probability of being in a state after n steps?

Tags: markov-chains, data-analysis

Assuming we start at state 0:

[image]

[image]

Attached is a picture of the transition matrix and the problem I am trying to figure out. I understand that we have to go from 0 to 7, giving that a probability of .5, and I understand the n-1 being the steps from 7 to itself. However, I'm having a hard time understanding where the 0.4 comes from.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very sloppily drawn diagram because they do not label the self-loops explicitly. The point is that there is only 0.6 worth of outgoing edges from state 7, which means that by conservation of probability there must be a self-loop with weight 0.4 from state 7 to itself.

Comment: So its the .4 + .2 going out from seven subtracted from 1? (1-(.4+.2))?

Comment: Of course, because "probability of staying at 7" + "probability of leaving 7" = 1.

Comment: ok. that makes sense. what if i wanted the probability of being in state 4 after n steps?

Comment: @gracie Well, now you need to go to 7 in the first step (because you cannot stay at 0), stay at 7 for some number m steps, then go to 4, then stay at 4 for k steps, where the total number of steps is n.